# Problem with delete operation in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have problem with **Delete** operation in my app.

I tried to use my other Delete actions, but I was getting errors.

I'm using Controller, Interface and then View.
Maybe I should give up with Interface?

Here is my **ManageCategories** View:

```html
@model collector_forum.Models.Category.CategoryIndexModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categories list";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="Lists">

    <h1 class="headersTable">List of all categories</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive-xl">
            <table class="table table-hover usersList">
                <tr style="font-size: 20px; marker:none;">
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Action</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var category in Model.CategoryList)
                {
                    <tr style="font-size: 16px;">
                        <td class="align-middle">@category.Id</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">@category.Name</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">@category.Description</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">
                            <div btn-group align-middle>
                                <form asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Forum" asp-route-id="@category.Id" method="post">
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Forum" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@category.Id">Edit</a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete category: @category.Name')">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here "copied and edited" **Delete** action:

```cs
public IActionResult Delete(int categoryId)
        {
            var category =  _categoryService.GetById(categoryId);

            if (category == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Category with ID = {categoryId} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            else
            {
                var result = _categoryService.Delete(categoryId);

                if (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageCategories");
                }

                return View("ManageCategories");
            }
        }
```

And the file Im referring to in **Delete** action

```cs
namespace collector_forum.Data
{
    public interface ICategory
    {
        Category GetById(int id);
        IEnumerable<Category> GetAll();
        Task Create (Category category);
        Task Delete (int categoryId);
        Task UpdateCategoryTitle(int categoryId, string newTitle);
        Task UpdateCategoryDescription(int categoryId, string newDescription);
        IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetActiveUsers(int id);
        bool HasRecentPost(int id);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that ID is [null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZe8F.png)?

Please, help

I forgot **CategoryIndexModel**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace collector_forum.Models.Category
{
    public class CategoryIndexModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CategoryListingModel> CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has a wrong route key for `categoryId`, it should be `asp-route-categoryId="@category.Id"`.

Note that if you don't define a route pattern with a placeholder for id like `{id}`, this `asp-route-id` will render the post URL as query string with a parameter name of `id`, like `?id=...`. So if you don't define a route pattern (such as by using `RouteAttribute`), you can use the `FromQueryAttribute` to bind the `categoryId` parameter with the query value of `id` like this:

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromQuery(Name="id")] int categoryId) { ... }
```

Or if you define some route pattern for your `id` (e.g: `Route("/delete/{id}")`), because the parameter name is different, you need to use the `FromRouteAttribute` like this:

```
Route("/delete/{id}")
public IActionResult Delete([FromRoute(Name="id")] int categoryId) { ... }
```

I think you should use `asp-route-` with a matched parameter name so that you don't need to use any attributes (to specify the name explicitly).

Comment: But `asp-route-id=" "` is working fine in other View.

Comment: @Piotr it's not working against the views, it's working against ***actions or handlers***. In this case it's not working for your `Delete` method due to the reason I said in my answer. If you want to keep `asp-route-id`, you can use the custom attributes I mentioned in my answer. Or you can rename `categoryId` to just `id`.

Comment: @Piotr OK, you should accept the answer then (click the tick mark), that's how SO works.