# Problem with foreach loop ASP.Net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, foreach

[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870402/problem-with-delete-operation-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

It is with reference to the previous post above.

Is there something wrong with the foreach loop or Action **ManageCategories**?

The page loads normally, but after removing the category, it cannot pass through the foreach loop

View:

```html
@model collector_forum.Models.Category.CategoryIndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Categories";
}

<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row sectionHeader">
        <div class="sectionHeading">Browse Categories</div>
        <div class="sectionDescription">
            <p>Welcome to <strong>Collectors Forum community</strong>. Posts are categorized by their theme</p>
            <p>
                Please read the Forum Guidelines before creating a new post.
                @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <span>
                        You must be a
                        <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">registered member</a>
                        to create a new post
                    </span>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="row" id="categoryIndexContent">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="categoryIndexTable">
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var category in Model.CategoryList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @*<div class="forumLogo" style="background-image: url(@category.ImageUrl);"></div>*@
                            <div class="categoryData">
                                <div class="categoryTitle">
                                    <a asp-controller="Forum" asp-action="Topic" asp-route-id="@category.Id">@category.Name</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="categorySubTitle">
                                    @if (category.HasRecentPost)
                                    {
                                        <div class="hasRecentPost">Hot</div>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="categoryPostCount">
                                @category.NumberOfPosts Posts
                            </div>
                            <div class="categoryMemberCount">
                                @category.NumberOfUsers Users
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="categoryDescription">
                                @category.Description
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTUq1.png)

And here code of my **Delete** Action:

```cs
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var category =  _categoryService.GetById(id);


            if (category == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Category with ID = {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            else
            {
                var result = _categoryService.Delete(id);

                if (result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageCategories");
                }

                return View("ManageCategories");
            }
        }
```

What went wrong?

**ManageCategories** Action:

```cs
public IActionResult ManageCategories()
        {
            var categories = _categoryService.GetAll()
               .Select(category => new CategoryListingModel
               {
                   Id = category.Id,
                   Name = category.Title,
                   Description = category.Description
               });

            var model = new CategoryIndexModel
            {
                CategoryList = categories
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

After debugging method Delete seems doesn't work = > [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKIEe.png)

**Delete** Action

```cs
public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            var category = GetById(id);
            _context.Remove(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: `Model` appears to be null.

Comment: But how? Page is normally loading first time through foreach loop, and after delete category it's not

Comment: Could you please post the action that uses the view. I can't see any code that fills your `Model` so the question is not "how it can be null" but "how it's populated".

Comment: Could you post  the ManageCategories action pls? I couldn't find it in your previous post.

Answer (score 0):

You may change

```
return View("ManageCategories");
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("ManageCategories");
```

Comment: I don't think that solve my issue, because now with Redirect instead View after click "Delete" button nothing happens exept refreshing page

Comment: I think the delete failed and `result.IsCompletedSuccessfully` is false, so there is nochange

Comment: How can I replace it?

Comment: It is based on your codes, you should debug to check how it goes in the Delete action. If the category with the id is successfully deleted, data in page should change.

Comment: I think is not successfully, because doesn't pass through if condition